# AdMob Ads Not Functioning Correctly: A Flutter Problem

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-studio, google-mobile-ads

I am new to Flutter and have been learning for a month. I have been implementing the AdMob ads into my Flutter project following the instructions on the AdMob documentation, and the test ads are appearing correctly. However, I have noticed that the close button on the display ads appears broken, and it is displayed twice. I know from my experience with Android and Java that this shouldn't appear this way. This caused me to check the logcat, where I noticed two warnings displayed.

**Denying clipboard access to com.google.android.gms, application is not in focus nor is it a system service for user 0**

**Received log message: Google:HTML You are currently using version 232400999.230500000.1 of the SDK, which is out of date. Please consider updating your SDK to the most recent SDK version to get the latest features and bug fixes. The latest SDK can be installed from https://googlemobileadssdk.page.link/android-install-instructions. More information about the SDK deprecation schedule is available at https://developers.google.com/admob/android/deprecation.**

The second warning is really strange because I am using the latest version 3.0.0 of the google mobile sdk, below i how I implemented the ads.

````
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  runApp(Gameplay());
}
//Loading the ads
  void loadAdmobAd() {
    InterstitialAd.load(
        adUnitId: adUnitId,
        request: const AdRequest(),
        adLoadCallback: InterstitialAdLoadCallback(
          // Called when an ad is successfully received.
          onAdLoaded: (ad) {
            ad.fullScreenContentCallback = FullScreenContentCallback(
              // Called when the ad showed the full screen content.
                onAdShowedFullScreenContent: (ad) {},
                // Called when an impression occurs on the ad.
                onAdImpression: (ad) {},
                // Called when the ad failed to show full screen content.
                onAdFailedToShowFullScreenContent: (ad, err) {
                  // Dispose the ad here to free resources.
                  ad.dispose();
                },
                // Called when the ad dismissed full screen content.
                onAdDismissedFullScreenContent: (ad) {
                  // Dispose the ad here to free resources.
                  ad.dispose();
                },
                // Called when a click is recorded for an ad.
                onAdClicked: (ad) {});

            debugPrint('$ad loaded.');
            // Keep a reference to the ad so you can show it later.
            _interstitialAd = ad;
          },
          // Called when an ad request failed.
          onAdFailedToLoad: (LoadAdError error) {
            debugPrint('InterstitialAd failed to load: $error');
          },
        ));
  }
//showing the ads
 void showAdmobAds(){
    _interstitialAd?.show();
  } ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pXF4s.png
````